# java connection with SQL(java.lang...)

Tags: java, sql

I have a really big problem with my java code.

Here is my code in Action listener on button.

The exception is:

> in output writen(java.lang.nullpointerexception)

Thanks for help.

```
    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

    // # declaration

    String naw_syani=naw.getText();
    String zhmara_f=zhmara_form.getText().trim();
    String zhmara_nas=zhmara_nasnama.getText().trim();
    String zhmara_mob=zhmara_mobile.getText().trim();
    String zhmara_mob2=zhmara_mobile2.getText().trim();
    String zhmara_mall=zhmara_xanw.getText().trim();
    String barwar=jDateChooser2.getDateFormatString();

    // # connection

    PreparedStatement stat;
    ResultSet rs;

    String sql ="insert into xallk values ('"+"', 'mitan', 'moran', 'mimie', 245,235);";
    try 
    {
       stat = (PreparedStatement) conn.prepareCall(sql);
       stat.execute();
       System.out.println("chw");
    }
    catch (SQLException e) 
    {
         System.out.println("insert nabw!"+e);
    }

}
```

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: in the catch, in output->java.lang.nullpointerexception !

Comment: have you trried to test if conn is not null?

Comment: emm.. ishould say i'm begginer of the  java programming, i guess that U mean: "it is connected to DB ?" . Yes its connected

Comment: Sounds like there is missing code. Also the error message is on which line of code?

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix the error in the run!clean & build is complete, while in run it gives me this exception, and it is not telling you wich line contain error!,there is is a catch  that print (e), maybe this line